# pages and files Permissions in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, customization, membership

I'm newbie in wordpress and I just graduated a postrgesql's course.

I want to add to my web a membership-engine that asks for username and password and for each user its will give access for just some of the files.
Kind of private different "mini-site" for each user.
also I want to add a custom calender with custom events for each user.
I know how to build a users' database in sql, but how to implement it, and all the above in my wordpress?

thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/). It's a free membership management framework for WordPress.